# php how to detect if you're running in Cygwin?

Tags: php, cygwin

how do you detect if you're running on Cygwin or not in php?

Answer (score 0):

use global PHP_OS constant

```php
if(\PHP_OS === 'CYGWIN'){
 // running in cygwin
} else {
// not running in cygwin
}
```